# ASP.Net 4 with existing non relational database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a reasonably competent c# developer but have primarily been doing GUI and command line tools, recently been asked to begin looking at creating a small web app to allow mobile devices to maintain the data in one of our databases.

The database is an SQL 2008 R2 database that while the tables to relate to one another there are no foreign keys or any DDL relationships defined.

**My question:** Where should I begin to get this simple app up? I'm only editing around 7-10 tables which are mostly related (Object, object location history, object ervice history etc). I am happy to provide some table DDL if that helps in the decision.

It doesn't need to be anything fancy, just a way users can look up the objects and modify them as well as add new entries to the linked tables (service history / location history)

I have looked into a few different methods but am really struggling to find good examples on creating a simple web site/app based on an existing database without the FK DDL contained within, and again I am happy to provide any extra details upon request.

Comment: Maybe the first thing would be to build up those constraints

Comment: I am unable to alter the database in any way as it's a 3rd party application otherwise I have found plenty of examples online/msdn that could suit.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Display and edit some data gathered from DB?

Comment: On the simplest level I have 3 tables. Objects, ObjectLocationHistory, ObjectServiceHistory - I need to display the Object and its details, its location history, its service history and allow the user to edit the Object and its details as well as add a new service or location history item relating to the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use the designer in Entity Framework.

Both nhibernate and entity framework (and most other OR/M) allows you to work with databases that has no FKs. But you'll have to create the mappings by yourself.

**nhibernate**

I personally prefer fluent nhibernate over the built in code mappings in nhibernate: http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/

**Entity framework**

You can create mappings for entity framework too:

- http://elegantcode.com/2009/12/15/entity-framework-poco-ef4-a-simple-mapping/
- [Entity Framework Code First Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720889/entity-framework-code-first-mapping)

**Vanilla ADO.NET**

You can of course use plain ADO.NET. Combine it with the repository pattern. Probably the fastest way to get a simple app up and running.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! After some preliminary reading that seems like the right direction. I Will have a proper play tomorrow with it and get back to you.

Comment: Thankyou, I ended up creating a Linq To SQL Dynamic Data project and defining the relationships manually using Associations. So far so good.

Answer (score 0):

You should build your application like any other with FK DDL. Probably it would result errors in data, but .....  SISO (Stupid Input Stupid Output).